# Preventing 1 level/value of pandas df column from being plotted

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I have just started using python for data visualization. I have searched google & stackoverflow but was unable to find an answer to my problem. Hopefully you might be able to help:

I have a pandas df with several data rows per person (id), and 2 other columns named StimCat (3 levels: A,B,C) & rt (continuous values, reaction times) e.g. like this:

```
   id  StimCat rt
0  1     A    596
1  1     B    657
2  1     C    200
3  1     C    354
4  1     A    164
5  2     A    164
6  2     B    343
7  2     B    264
8  2     A    456
9  2     C    523 
10 2     C    241
```

I wrote the following code to plot the mean data for each StimCat level grouped by id:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,7))            
df.groupby(['id','StimCat']).mean()['rt'].unstack().plot.bar(ax=ax)
```

However, I actually only want to plot 2 out of 3 levels for StimCat, namely A and B, but omit level C from the plots entirely.

Any hints on how I could do this? Or if such a question has been asked before (which I haven't found yet), you could hopefully point me to the respective entry? Thank you everyone!!!! I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not going to plot it, don't calculate it. Use `query`/boolean indexing/`eval`/`isin` and filter it out.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,7)) 

df.query('StimCat != "C"')\
  .groupby(['id','StimCat'])\
  .mean()['rt']\
  .unstack()\
  .plot.bar(ax=ax)
```

[image]

If your aim is to exclude multiple such categories, try something like this -

```
cat_to_exclude = ['A', 'C'] # filter out categories A and C, for example
df = df.query('StimCat not in @cat_to_exclude')

df

   id StimCat   rt
1   1       B  657
6   2       B  343
7   2       B  264
```

And then perform the `groupby`.